# Extending HtmlHelper in .NET 4.0 MVC3 ASPX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, html-helper

I have code that works in a .NET 3.5 app that isn't working when I set it up the same way in .NET 4.0. The problem comes when I try to extend HtmlHelper. In .NET 4.0 MVC3, if I have a page that looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable (Of MvcApplication2.MyModel))" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%=Html.MyTest%>
</asp:Content>
```

and an extension like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Extensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function MyTest(htmlhelper As System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper) As String
        Return Now.ToLongTimeString
    End Function

End Module
```

it won't compile, because "Html" is not of type `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper` like it was in the past, it's now of type `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(Of IEnumerable (Of MvcApplication2.MyModel))`. The error message on `<%=Html.MyTest%>` is:

```
'MyTest' is not a member of 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of MvcApplication2.MyModel))'.
```

How would I extend HtmlHelper in this configuration? Am I missing something in my setup that's causing "Html" to be of a different type than it was in the past? I haven't found anything online about a change in behavior, which leads me to believe that I've done something wrong somewhere.

**UPDATE:**

In reference to HtmlHelper(Of TModel) inheriting from HtmlHelper, why won't this code work?

```
Partial Public Class HtmlHelper

    Public Function MyOtherTest() As String
        Return Now.ToLongTimeString
    End Function

End Class
```

Referencing `<%=Html.MyOtherTest%>` produces the same error message.

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: I suspect I had something wrong in web.config. I'm not sure exactly what, because I re-converted my project, then methodically went through the web.config to make sure I had the right setup, and this time it worked (probably the pages\namespaces section). You're response kept me from going down a whole different path though, so that's much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views with typed models get typed HTML helpers so that helper methods can use the model type.
However, `HtmlHelper(Of TModel)` inherits `HtmlHelper`, so your code will work fine.

It's possible that you've added a reference to `System.Web.WebPages.dll`, so that the extension method is extending `System.Web.WebPages.HtmlHelper`, which is a different class.

Comment: There are no references to System.Web.WebPages.dll, and to make sure I updated the extension to "Public Function MyTest(htmlhelper As System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper) As String", so there should be no confusion, but it still says MyTest is not a member.

Comment: Can't you just change the parameter type to `(htmlhelper As System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(Of TModel))`, i.e. extend the generic class?

Comment: @Rup: That shouldn't be necessary, since it inherits `HtmlHelper`.